# cannot uninstall Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, windows-server-2012-r2

I have tried to uninstall Visual Studio 2015 via *Programs and Features* but the uninstaller is not there. So, I started searching around and I found this in one blog somewhere:

> - First go to C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{37e19555-e88d-4aed-9d42-82d0784d2b79}
> - run vs_enterprise.exe /uninstall /force via a command prompt

But the **{37e19555-e88d-4aed-9d42-82d0784d2b79}** folder does not exist and I can't seem to find `vs_enterprise.exe` any where in my computer.

I am not sure what has happened to Visual Studio 2015, and why I can't find the `vs_enterprise.exe`, but VS opens OK.

**Update:**

I have Wwindows Server 2012 R2 and I have tried to do a repair, but as I said above, I could not see the uninstall option in *Programs and Features*.

So, I run the installer from the ISO image, and to my surprise it did not ask me if I wanted to uninstall visual studio 2015, but was asking to install it.

I thought perhaps it is a good idea to install it again and that might overwrite the existing installation. But what it did was a new installation above the current one, because when I ran the uninstaller the previous installation was there. Very strange.

Any idea how to uninstall it?

Comment: What folders reside under C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\ ?

Comment: Try to use a 3rd party software like Revo uninstaller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use this VS uninstaller which you can find in GitHub https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases.

```
Usage:
0. Extract TotalUninstaller.zip
1.Open an administrator command prompt.
2.Execute Setup.ForcedUninstall.exe
3.Type 'Y' to uninstall.
```

Have a look at this as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt720585.aspx

Comment: the tool helped a lot. I was able to uninstall it. Thank you for your help guys. All of you.

Comment: Doesn't work. Stuck at `Uninstalling: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{79b486b9-c5f0-4096-a00c-8351f59587c2}\vs_community.exe`.

Comment: I'm currently running this and I guess it's going to uninstall about 232 programs, right? I'm not sure I want this but anyway, I'm trying.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to repair VS2015 first as described on the MS support site?
Also you didn't mention what OS you are you using (the repair option works only on Win 7 and earlier) so I am assuming you are using Windows 7:

"In the Programs and Features window, right-click Visual Studio, select Change, and then click Repair to start the repair process."

[From MS support site - Multiple feature installation errors in Windows 7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3039361/common-issues-in-visual-studio-2015-setup)